# Easy input stress mark with apostrophe in US keyboards

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that changes the way apostrophes work in International US keyboards.

They normally work by pressing ' once and then a vowel for an accent (á,é,í,ó,ú) or a consonant for an apostrophe ('m'l) and so for an apostrophe before a vowel ('a,'o) you need to double press then backspace then type the vowel.

This double press then backspace is the bottleneck I'm trying to solve here.

I've come up with this solution to the problem:

```
/* Bit of code A */
$'::Send `'{Space}
$+a::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "$'") ? "{bs}á" : "a"
$+e::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "$'") ? "{bs}é" : "e"
$+i::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "$'") ? "{bs}í" : "i"
$+o::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "$'") ? "{bs}ó" : "o"
$+u::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "$'") ? "{bs}ú" : "u"
```

this makes so the ' only becomes an accent in case shift is pressed while typing the vowel but as you may have noticed this also breaks "alt capitalization" for vowels on my keyboard.
I've tried creating a parallel script that would make them behave normally when not preceded by '

```
/* Bit of code B */
$+a::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "") ? "A" : "a"
$+e::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "") ? "E" : "e"
$+i::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "") ? "I" : "i"
$+o::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "") ? "O" : "o"
$+u::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "") ? "U" : "u"
```

But this cannot run as the two scripts overlap and this would only solve capitalization at the begging of a sentence.

So it should be:

```
/* Bit of code C */
$+a::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "anything other than '") ? "A" : "a"
$+e::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "anything other than '") ? "E" : "e"
$+i::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "anything other than '") ? "I" : "i"
$+o::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "anything other than '") ? "O" : "o"
$+u::Send % (A_PriorHotkey = "anything other than '") ? "U" : "u"
```

How can I structure my code to if (A_PriorHotkey = "'") run `/* Bit of code A */` else
`/* Bit of code C */`.

Comment: Have you tried hotstrings? For example, `:*:``a::á` (two ticks required since it's an escape character in AHK, but just one needed to activate). However, it doesn't require the use of shift, though it will conform to the case you use, so you can make both á and Á.

Comment: Oops, you'd also need the `?` option use it in words. `:*?:``a::á`

Answer (score 0):

## 1 use different keyboard layer

[two keyboard layer by AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=69859)

In here we press twice <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to switch keyboard layer. You can see left top have a GUI can remind you your keyboard layer.

```
; AutoHotkey v1

keyboard_state = 0

intInterval := 300
~LAlt::
    if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~LAlt" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > intInterval)
    {
        KeyWait, LAlt
        return
    }
    Else {
        if (keyboard_state = 1 ){
            EnvAdd, keyboard_state ,-1
            Gui,Destroy
        }
        Else {
             EnvAdd, keyboard_state ,1
            ;SoundBeep, 200, 300
            showtext(1)
        }
    }
return

#if (keyboard_state = 1)

; Write your setting in here
:*:a::á
:*:e::é
:*:i::í
:*:u::ó
:*:o::ú
#if ; End #if


showtext(str)
{
    x := 10
    y := 10
    Gui,Destroy
    Gui,+AlwaysOnTop +Disabled -Caption -SysMenu +Owner +LastFound
    WinGet,hwnd,ID
    Gui, font, s26 ECF3F7 w600, Verdana
    Gui, Color, ECF3F7
    WinSet, TransColor, ECF3F7
    Gui,Add,Text,BackgroundTrans,%str%
    Gui, Show, NoActivate Y%y% X%x% NA, Title of Window
}
```

## 2 use inputbox

you can use a shortcut active a simple inputbox. You input one of a,e,i,o,u it will send á,é,í,ó,ú

## 3 use Hotstrings

Like @EJE says. We only need simple Hotstrings. Input ' ' a can input á.

```
"*:''a::á
```